# Nginx: How to redirect a location within a location?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to redirect `http://test.com/support` or `http://test.com/support/` to `https://support.test.com` AND I need to redirect anything that is `http://test.com/support/*` to `https://support.test.com/*`

this is the Code I have right now and it does the second half, but not the first... Any ideas would be helpful.

```
    location /support {
            proxy_pass         http://support.test.com;
            proxy_set_header Host "support.test.com";
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

I would assume that there has to be am if statement inside the location block, but i am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the location to an regex like that?

```
location ~* ^/support(?:/|\z) {
        proxy_pass ...
}
```